# Adapting old code single-thread code to multiprocessing using a dictionary for multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have the following function to parallelize some tasks:

```
def parallelize(func, variable_args, proc_count=None):
    if proc_count is None:
        proc_count = multi.cpu_count()

    warnings.warn('You have {n_cpu} CPU. Tasks will be distributed over all.'.format(n_cpu=proc_count))

    pool = multi.Pool(processes=proc_count)
    result = pool.map(func, variable_args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return result
```

And I have a bunch of old functions that look like:

```
def some_old_function(that_,takes_,lots_of_,arguments_):
    do_stuff_single_thread()
```

What I have been doing so far to "parallelize" these functions is recode them to look like:

```
def some_old_function(dict_arg):
     that_ = dict_arg['that']
     takes_= dict_arg['takes_']
     ...
     do_stuff_single_thread()
```

And lastly call:

```
parallelize(some_old_function, list_of_dict_args)
```

I am writing becuase I worry there must be a more "pythonic" way to do this than what I have chosen to do above.

I appreciate any advice I receive.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly usable. Given that pool workers only accept a single argument, you have to make that a data structure of some kind if the function you're calling inside the worker needs more than one argument.

You could also use a tuple instead of a dict, and then use the star operator. That makes calling easier:

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr 11 2019, 01:11:37) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def test(a,b,c):
...     print a, b, c
... 
>>> args = (1, 2, 3)
>>> test(*args)
1 2 3
```

In this case you don't have to manually unpack the dictionary. But you have to make sure that the arguments in the tuple are in the right order and the correct amount...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that involves less rewriting would be to take your iterables of individual arguments (one each for all `that_`s, all `takes_`s, all `lots_`s, etc.), `zip` them together, then use `Pool`'s `starmap` method, that unpacks `tuple`s as sequential positional arguments for you.

Alternatively, rather than recoding `some_old_function`, make a trivial wrapper that unpacks the `dict` to the "real" function, e.g.

```
def some_old_function_wrapper(kwargs):
    return some_old_function(**kwargs)
```

You'd still pass your `list_of_dicts` as in your current design, but `some_old_function` would remain unchanged, and you'd let Python do the unpacking (which is going to be faster and cleaner than explicit argument by argument lookup).